# Selenium WebDriver code cannot track elements in the window, having no Title or URL

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am on a page. After clicking on a link, a new window is opening. The window does not have any URL or title. So, while switching to the new window, aftre I am inspecting element, &, creating Xpath, Selenium code can't focus on the new window, and is not executing anything after that. Can you please resolve my query?

**Note**: After I inspect, the console window title is showing the URL of the parent window.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch between different open windows you have opened:

```
String storeCurrentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

Then perform the click operation that opens a new window

Make a switch to the new window that has opened

```
    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
```

Do whatever the test needs within the selected window

Then close the new window, if it is no longer required

```
driver.close();
```

And switch back to the first window that had been opened

```
driver.switchTo().window(storeCurrentWindowHandler);
```

Hopefully this will help you to solve your issue.

Comment: No, my query is I cannot perform any operations in the new window. I can inspect elements, but teh Xpaths are not working in code. The new window does not have any URL or title.

Comment: Can you try to get the element by CSS Selector https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/css-selector-selenium-locator-selenium-tutorial-6/

Comment: Tried wuth CSS Selector as suggested by you. But, it is not working.